# Send and receive audio between PC and iPhone

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, iphone

I would like to be able to use my headset for both my phone and PC at once. eg. Audio would play from both my phone, and any applications on my PC, and both my phone and PC will be able to pick up audio from my microphone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although the method will differ depending on your phone type.

Jabra https://www.jabra.com/blog/multipoint-explained-one-headset-for-all-devices/ offers simultaneous connections to two devices, so all calls would not need to be routed through one PC.

There are also [Bluetooth transceivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0749FQ93G) which accept headphone plugs (3.5mm) and allow that headphone to work over Bluetooth.

Now, I don't need that, and instead use a Logitech H800 in Win10 to stream music; when a VOIP phone call arrives, the PC passes the call to the headset and I can take the call. However, music does not stop, and I must pause the music manually.

I have not interfaced that Logitech to either a landline phone or a cell phone; which kind of phone do you use? If you have your cellphone or landline also ring a VOIP number terminating in your PC, you could do this. I have set up both landlines and cell phones to ring two phones at once, and it worked well. This approach does not require having a Bluetooth headset which can connect to multiple devices at once; all connections are through one PC.

Comment: I have an iPhone, and the idea wasn't specifically for calls; it's for any audio. I know that I can use my PC's mic and pass that through to the phone via an app, so I wondered if this could be extended to both input and output.

Comment: Yes, as per Jabra's page, linked in the first graf above.

Comment: Unfortunately, my headset is a wired one, through the front panel audio jacks.

Comment: So you will need an iOS app which uses the PC to handle interfacing the wired headset. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is the place to look for help with that, as I am a telephony and PC guy with little ken o' iOS .

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look.

Comment: I’d say it’s very unlikely that you will be able to do that with an app on a non jailbroken phone. That’s just not how iOS really works.

Comment: @Jammy Dodger https://www.amazon.com/Mpow-Bluetooth-Transmitter-Wireless-Enjoyment/dp/B0749FQ93G may also hep solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I do not believe that is possible for music or such.  Depending on the capabilities of your headset though, you could be connected to your pc and streaming music and when you get a phone call on your Iphone, some headphones can be dual connected to different devices and the headphones will stop the music and play your ringtone.

Otherwise, perhaps you can look into "stereo mix" on Windows machine.   Stereo mix feature 'used to', unsure if it still does, would allow you to output audio from your pc  to multiple devices.  E.G. Whatever you have connected to the headphone jack would play the exact same audio at the same time as it played it thru the laptop speakers.

Finally,  either I am understanding you incorrect or I don't think you thought thru your idea very thoroughly.  Have you ever been listening to a song you enjoyed on your radio in your car and then a passenger starts playing music thru a bluetooth speaker very loudly at the same time?   The results are not enjoyable to either person.   As for recording your mic feed,  If you are too close to the audio output device and your mic can pickup a 'loop' of your microphone, you'll get a head splitting migraine from the painfully high pitched dinging that flawlessly occurs in that situation.